# I/O voltage compatibility checks as part of design rule checks during schematic design

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, design-rules

Schematic design programs have concept of design rule checks. What exactly does this feature check?

Can it check if the input voltage on different pins of an IC is compatible with its I/O voltage? For this the schematic design program would need to have concept of I/O voltage, power supply voltage and be able to work out if they are compatible or not. This means that one can find out if we are driving a 3.3V input buffer from a 5V net or driving a 5V input buffer from a 1.2V net.

Comment: What exactly it does check or can check depends on the EDA package you're using. It's likely that some package would support that, but at least some can only do rudimentary net drivenness and IO direction/use checking.

Comment: It has happened in the past that 3.3V clock signal was connected to 1.8V input among other things. I think that schematic tools should themself be able to carry out such a basic test based on the power supply rail information that is also provided to them anyway. I find it strange that this has not yet become a normal part of schematic design process and tools.

Comment: We need AI, lots of it.

Comment: The schematic design program would need a simulator. Even if it knew it was a 3.3V output, that information is gone when it goes through a resistor or other component, unless there is a simulator embedded to simulate things. It is just simpler that a engineer designing the circuit knows what kind of inputs each device has and connects it appropriately.